# meaning of とが in this sentence

Tags: particle-が, particle-と

I saw this in news:
アパートで、３０前後と見られ男性が血まみれで、死亡しているところとが見つかれました。

Can anyone explain what is the use of とが in this sentence, and maybe provide some examples?

Comment: Please check this sentence again. I think it would be 死亡しているところが見つかりました.

Comment: Also, `３０前後と見られ男性が` should be ３０前後と見られ**る**男性が

Comment: Ah, so I'm not the only one who thought of using sentences from Death Note for learning ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think 
「アパートで、３０前後と見られ**る**男性が、血まみれで死亡している **のが 見つかり**ました。」
is correct.

**の** is almost the same as  **こと**, and **が** is a particle which follows a subject.

When **の/こと** follows an adjective or a verb, they change to a noun.

死亡している (dead) : adjective

死亡している **こと** (to be dead) : noun

読む (read) : verb

読む **こと** (to read) : noun

Regarding the difference of の and こと, when the main verb of the sentence is a perceptive verb like *see, hear, know, etc.*, **の** is used very often.

⭕ 彼が踊る **の** を見た (I saw him dancing.)

❌ 彼が踊る **こと** を見た

Comment: `死亡している (dead) : adjective` ← English "dead" is an adjective, but is 死亡している really an adjective/形容詞?

Comment: Maybe a "verbal adjective"?